# WebRTC VideoView incorrect view for local peer

Tags: android, webrtc, android-videoview, webrtc-android

I am writing a WebRTC solution and having an issue in Local View while using back camera (Wrong Rotation / Incorrect View)

```
<com.src.webrtc.android.VideoView
     android:id="@+id/main_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Local View (Incorrect view)

[image]

Remote View (Correct View : while viewing as a Remote user)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue while working on the webRTC. I fixed it by setting the method setMirror(false).

here's some code:
call_activity.xml

```
<org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_video_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
    android:id="@+id/pip_video_view"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

in CallActivity.java

```
SurfaceViewRenderer fullscreenRenderer = 
findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_video_view);
fullscreenRenderer.init(eglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
fullscreenRenderer.setScalingType(ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL);
fullscreenRenderer.setEnableHardwareScaler(false /* enabled */);
//this code is used for rotation
fullscreenRenderer.setMirror(false);
```

I am using `implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28513'`

Update:
what you can do in VideoView.kt is:

```
class VideoView : SurfaceViewRenderer{
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: android.util.AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

fun init(rendererEvents: RendererCommon.RendererEvents?) {
    super.init(EglBaseProvider.getEglBase(this).eglBaseContext, rendererEvents)
    setMirror(false)
}

override fun release() {
    super.release()
    EglBaseProvider.release(this)
}

override fun setMirror(mirror: Boolean) {
    super.setMirror(mirror)
}
}
```

or

```
class VideoView : SurfaceViewRenderer{
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: android.util.AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

fun init(rendererEvents: RendererCommon.RendererEvents?) {
    super.init(EglBaseProvider.getEglBase(this).eglBaseContext, rendererEvents)
    super.setMirror(false)
}

override fun release() {
    super.release()
    EglBaseProvider.release(this)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Kindly check above code I just shared of VideoView.kt class of my SDK.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. I hope this will fix your rotation issue.

Comment: thank you so much rotation issue fixed with .setMirror(false)

Comment: Just asked, I believe you would like to give a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439358/webrtc-videoview-black-screen-while-switch-to-and-from-inbuilt-camera-app